# Non random matrix as instrument: consistency and bias

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, applied-econometrics

Where can I find references to see what happens theoretically if I want to use a non random matrix as instrument in terms of consistency and bias?

Comment: Not sure if this link may help: https://eml.berkeley.edu/~mcfadden/e240b_f01/ch4.pdf